# HP Fanfic where Death Eaters attack Hermione at her parents' home

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, death-eaters, hermione-granger

I’m trying to find a specific HP fanfic I read a couple years ago, where Hermione is in her home with her parents. It's the middle of the night when Death Eaters attack,  I beleive Hermione is in the kitchen drinking water when they break in.

They torture Hermione's mom and dad in front of her, trying to get information on the Order, the Burrow location, and Harry. Hermione doesn't break and they kill her parents in front of her. They then move to torturing her for multiple hours. When they finally stop and leave,  Hermione is barely hanging on when she is saved (I believe by Dumbledore).

Answer (score 2):

**Perhaps [*Run Away Hermione*](http://hp.adult-fanfiction.org/story.php?no=600014736)?**

Pertinent segment:

> ...Hermione Granger whose (parents?) were murdered on the 23rd of this month by death eaters. It has been said that Ms. Granger, who was
> forced to watch the brutal murder of her parents, was found tied to a
> wall in her family Home by Local Muggle Police.

**Or perhaps [*Never Underestimate a Witch*](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/12297866/2/Never-Underestimate-A-Witch)?**

Pertinent segments:

> *"Crucio!"*
>
> Hermione sobbed as the agonizing screams of her mum and dad filled her ears

....

> As the torture of her parents went on, with
> Hermione forced to watch

.....

> Voldemort mused, stroking his chin. "Why did you bring her to me. I didn't ask you to. Explain to me why you thought it was a good idea to
> take on the risk of kidnapping the mudblood of the Golden Trio."

....

> "Well my lord, you see...The Order has been getting stronger, and
> getting in the way of your plans my lord. I thought the Granger girl
> would know where their headquarters were, or could at least provide
> some information on the members because of her close ties to Potter."

Comment: Is the bit in italics a quote?

Comment: @elemtilas Unfortunately that is not the one.